# Can I update related Parent and child object fields using Lightning Data Service without using Apex controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I know we can update fields using Lightning Data Service without using Apex controller.
Can I also update related Parent and child object fields using Lightning Data Service without using Apex controller?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm) you can understand that LDS supports it:

> Lightning Data Service supports spanned fields with a maximum depth of five levels. Support for working with collections of records or for querying for a record by anything other than the record ID isn’t available. If you must support higher-level operations or multiple operations in one transaction, use standard @AuraEnabled Apex methods.

I believe that as long as you have permission to edit the record - it will be supported.